# Whats the most basic way to go online in c++?

Tags: c++, urllib

What is the most basic way to go to a webpage and download its contents? the webpage i wish to get only has text, most of which is in tables.

is there a std library that does it (like `urllib` in python)?

Comment: Most recommendations will (rightly) recommend 3rd party components like libCURL.  There's nothing portabily native to most platforms.  If you have a specific platform/OS in mind, you might get better (targeted) answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A large number of tasks that are not covered by the C++ standard library can be done using boost, the collection of peer-reviewed portable libraries, which are used by pretty much every C++ project today. For networking, we use [boost.asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio.html).

Their tutorials include HTTP clients: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/client/sync_client.cpp and http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/client/async_client.cpp

However, although this is highly portable and may end up becoming part of the C++ standard library in future, it is a bit too low-level for  your task. [libCURL](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) is the today's default library for HTTP downloads.

Answer (score 6):

There's no official C++ network library, no. There are many different APIs available, though. Which is best for you would depend on what platform(s) you were targeting and what framework(s) you might already be using.

That said, [cpp-netlib](http://mikhailberis.github.com/cpp-netlib/) is a platform-neutral API that follows C++ idioms nicely. I've used it and it works.